# solve the Interrupted Exception of a thread in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a thread of the class AsyncTask that does something like this:

```
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Long... params) {

         while(true) {
            doSth();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}}
```

And then , somewhere I have to stop the thread, no matter whether it is sleeping or running, and this leads to Interrupted Exception.

I have 2 questions:

-Is this kind of exception serious and do I need to do something with it instead of just priningStackTrace()?

-Is it a right way to avoid this exception by using a doneFlag?

```
private boolean doneFlag = false;
  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Long... params) {

         while(true) {
            doSth();
                try {
                    doneFlag = false;

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    doneFlag = true;

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}}
```

And when I want to stop this AsyncTask Thread , I would do this:

```
   protected void cancelThread() {
    while (!this.isCancelled()) {
        if (doneFlag) {
            cancel(true);
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried the code above with doneFlag and the Interrupted Exception is not thrown. However, I am not sure if it has possible bugs or not?
Thank you very much for your help!